# The essential steps in verifying a file upload

Tags: file, file-upload

What would you say are the essential steps in verifying a file upload?

I'd tend to check the MIME type, give it a new (random) name, make sure its got an allowed file extension, and then I'd check the contents of the file. How do you go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Check (in this order): 
the file MIME type (and note certain browsers have MIME type detection problems...);
that the file path exists;
that a previous version of the file with the same name doesn't exist, else, rev it;
that the file isn't too big;
on success, run a virus check on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file type, check the file size, the image dimension.

These are the 3 I always check to be sure to have good result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving a gif file for a profile photo as example, you should check that the mime type is gif.
And that way you avoid uploading bad files.
[Here](http://www.jellyandcustard.com/2006/01/19/php-mime-types-and-fileinfo/) you have an example using php.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the expected file contents...  might be a good idea to run a virus scan on the file.